# Dagger 2 get own Room instance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-2

I want to add a callback to the room database to populate initial data.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRoom(context: Context): MyRoomDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyRoomDatabase::class.java, "my_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            @Override
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)

            }
        })
        .build()
}
```

For that i need the database instance in the callback to access DAO for inserting data.
How does this work?

**EDIT:**

**What I want to achieve:**
`Create initial data for the room database at the app installation`

My `Callback Class`:

```
class RoomCallback(
 var myRoomDatabase : MyRoomDatabase
)  : RoomDatabase.Callback()  {
override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    myRoomDatabase.basicItemDao().insertList(
        listOf(
            BasicItem(),
            BasicItem()
        )
    )
}
```

}

How i provide the `RoomDatabase` and the `RoomCallback`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRoom(context: Context, roomCallback: RoomCallback): MyRoomDatabase {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyRoomDatabase::class.java, "my_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .addCallback(roomCallback)    
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRoomCallback(myRoomDatabase: MyRoomDatabase): RoomCallback {
    return RoomCallback(myRoomDatabase)
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
- The `RoomCallback` and `RoomDatabase` instance need both the other instance.

Comment: I think you can create an Object(Singleton) that extends RoomDatabase.Callback() inside your base package, that does the insertion, and then pass that object inside addCallback()

Comment: @Debanjan I created a `RoomCallback` class and implemented RoomDatabase.Callback(). Now i wanted to provide this `RoomCallback` class with dagger but this class need the MyRoomDatabase Class. And the MyRoomDatabase class needs the RoomCallback class. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Lingo does my answer help?

Comment: @Maddy No Sorry, I know how to use Dagger2 in combination with Room. But at the part with populating data at the beginning I`ve problems.

Comment: @Lingo Can you edit your question with more details of your problem?

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: Using `Kotlin Coroutine` and `Dagger2`

Late in the party but for future readers, it's very easy to prepopulate your database at creation time or openning time. Make sure you have already added dependency in the `gradle` file for `Coroutine`. First create your database like:

```
    /**
     * Main database.
     */
    @Database(
        entities = [
            Login::class],
        version = 1,
        exportSchema = false
    )
    abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
        abstract fun loginDao(): LoginDao

        companion object {
            
            @Volatile private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

            fun getInstance(app: Application): AppDatabase = INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(app).also { INSTANCE = it }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(app: Application) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(app,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "your database name")
            .addCallback(object : Callback() {
                // Pre-populate the database after onCreate has been called. If you want to prepopulate at opening time then override onOpen function instead of onCreate.
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    // Do database operations through coroutine or any background thread
                    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
                        println("Caught during database creation --> $exception")
                    }

                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(handler) {
                        prePopulateAppDatabase(getInstance(app).loginDao())
                    }
                }
            })
            .build()

        suspend fun prePopulateAppDatabase(loginDao: LoginDao) {
            val admin = Login(0, "Administrator", "1234", 1, isActive = true, isAdmin = true, isLogged = false)
            loginDao.insertLoginData(admin)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can provide singleton instance by placing below code to your dagger `AppModule` or in a separate database module as you wish.

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDb(app: Application): AppDatabase {
    return AppDatabase.getInstance(app)
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideLoginDao(db: AppDatabase): LoginDao {
    return db.loginDao()
}
```

that's it, you are done. Inject anywhere your singleton database object like:

```
@Inject lateinit var loginDao: LoginDao
```

then use it.

Comment: But you have to do a dummy read...

Comment: @tomtomkt No dummy read is required.

Answer (score 5):

Setup a database first

```
@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    version = VERSION_CODE
)
abstract class DatabaseManager : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

Now create a DatabaseModule

```
@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoomDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): RoomDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, RoomDatabase::class.java, "dbName")
            .setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
            .build()
    }
}
```

You can create a separate module or add a method in `DatabaseModule` it self providing dao object. Say for example I have a `UserDao` then

```
@Module
class UserModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDao(database: DatabaseManager): UserDao {
        return database.userDao()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `.setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)` do?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51148013/4613320)

Comment: "you want to change the journal mode explicitly to Truncate, you can do it this way. But, it is not recommended because WAL is much better compared to Truncate" okay :D